# How to force histogram plots to have same axes?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, matplotlib, plotting, histogram

I am comparing my trained model with other benchmark models with the error histogram but the axis of histogram is different for each method as shown in figure[image].For instance to plot the error histogram of every method,I tried this code:

```
% Matlab code
Targets=Actual;
Outputs=Predicted_by_model;
errors=Targets-Outputs;
error_std=std(errors);
MAPE=mean(abs(Targets-Outputs)./Targets)*100;
histfit(errors);
legend('Proposed')
title(['MAPE = ' num2str(MAPE) '  ,    Error St.D. = ' num2str(error_std)]))
```

How to keep axis of every method to the same value.

Comment: You added the `matplotlib` library but your code is in Matlab. In which programming language you want your answer?

Comment: The above code is coded in MATLAB